# Why cannot type arguments be inferred from this simple code?

Tags: linq, compiler-construction, c#-3.0

Using .NET 3.5, but the `Select` call gives the error. Shouldn't the compiler be clever enough to infer this? If not, why not?

```
public IEnumerable<Customer> TableToCustomers(Table table)
{
    return table.Rows.Select(RowToCustomer);
}

private Customer RowToCustomer(TableRow row)
{
    return new Customer { ... };
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Rows` property is defined as `TableRowCollection Rows {get;}`

```
public sealed class TableRowCollection : IList, ICollection, IEnumerable
```

It is not `IEnumerable<TableRow>`, so it is just `IEnumerable`, therefore it cannot infer the type as being `TableRow`.

You can do this instead:

```
public IEnumerable<Customer> TableToCustomers(Table table)
{
    return table.Rows.Cast<TableRow>().Select(RowToCustomer);
}
```

Comment: What `Select` is this calling `IEnumerable`  ?

Comment: @Nix, I don't understand your question.  `System.Linq.Enumerable.Select<T,R>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T,R> func)`.  That is the Select function I'm talking about.  It has to be called on a /generic/ IEnumerable<T>, as I'm sure you are well aware.

Comment: you answered it, that's what I was thinking.

Comment: The `Cast<TableRow>` didn't work, still same error, but I understood the problem with your explanation and used a lambda expression finally. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
table.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Select(RowToCustomer);
```

Comment: It seems he is using `TableRow` and not `DataRow`